# Julia DefaultDict uses the same value (array) for each key

Tags: data-structures, julia, defaultdict

I want to create a defaultdict of arrays. Problem is, it uses the same array for each key.

```
# using Pkg
# Pkg.add("DataStructures")
using DataStructures: DefaultDict
genome = DefaultDict{Tuple{String, String}, Array{Int64, 1}}(Int64[])
push!(genome["chr1", "+"], 5)
# 1-element Array{Int64,1}:
# 5

push!(genome["chrX", "-"], 10)
# 2-element Array{Int64,1}:
#  5
# 10
```

I have tried feeding it a lambda to create a new array `x -> Int64`, but that just gave a type error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you literally used `x -> Int64`, then this doesn't make sense: your initiliazer doesn't need arguments, and it should return a value, not a type.  What you probably want to use is `() -> Int64[]`:

```
julia> genome = DefaultDict{Tuple{String, String}, Array{Int64, 1}}(() -> Int64[])
DefaultDict{Tuple{String,String},Array{Int64,1},getfield(Main, Symbol("##7#8"))} with 0 entries

julia> genome["a", "b"]
0-element Array{Int64,1}

julia> push!(genome["a", "c"], 5)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 5

julia> genome
DefaultDict{Tuple{String,String},Array{Int64,1},getfield(Main, Symbol("##7#8"))} with 2 entries:
  ("a", "c") => [5]
  ("a", "b") => Int64[]

julia> push!(genome["a", "b"], 4)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4

julia> genome
DefaultDict{Tuple{String,String},Array{Int64,1},getfield(Main, Symbol("##7#8"))} with 2 entries:
  ("a", "c") => [5]
  ("a", "b") => [4]
```

If you want to create a default value based on the tried key, you can use `passkey = true` together with an initializer function taking the key as an argument; see [the docs](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/latest/default_dict.html) for all options.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how to solve your problem using DefaultDict, but I think Julia's in-build dictionary structure offers a better solution. One can use

```
get!(collection, key, default)
```

to automatically give a default value where one hasn't been set already.
The above code would be rewritten:

```
genome = Dict{Tuple{String, String}, Array{Int64, 1}}()
push!(get!(genome, ("chr1", "+"), Int64[]), 5)
# 1-element Array{Int64,1}:
# 5

push!(get!(genome, ("chrX", "-"), Int64[]), 10)
# 1-element Array{Int64,1}:
# 10
```

Comment: Great answer, and the one I'll use, but the other answered the specific question so I accepted it so it will show at the top.